# Add-On File Upload option not available in Atlassian Jira

Tags: jira

We gotta problem while trying to add menu manager add-on. The '.obr' upload option is not available in the manage add-ons page. Please refer the attached screen shot. Can please advice how to make it done.

https://answers.atlassian.com/download/attachments/18449353/upload.png?version=1&modificationDate=1435239001062&api=v2

Also when we tried to give the Atlassian Marketplace url for the menu manager in the URL text box we get the below attached error.

https://answers.atlassian.com/download/attachments/18449353/error.png?version=1&modificationDate=1435239001058&api=v2

Can you please advise how to install the plugin?

Comment: You can find the Menu Manager plugin in the below link: (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.confluence.plugin.menumanager)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install arbitrary plugins into JIRA Cloud instance - only compatible ones.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the latest JIRA version?..so I guess your user need to have super user access privilege to install the plugin.so try with super user account.

or you can try to install the plugin manually download the .jar file form the market place and place the jar file in appropriate folder try with [this article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/__installing+a+JIRA+plugin+manually)